# What does <E> mean in Collection<E>?

Tags: java, generics, collections

What meaning has **`<E>`** on the code `Collection<E>`?

Comment: I need your help to learn the collections better.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's the use of generics. Check this [intro](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html) out. And then don't forget to read this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

An excerpt follows (which compares the use of a cast versus the use of generics):

> When you see the code <Type>, read it
>   as “of Type”; the declaration above
>   reads as “Collection of String c.” The
>   code using generics is clearer and
>   safer. We have eliminated an unsafe
>   cast and a number of extra
>   parentheses. More importantly, we have
>   moved part of the specification of the
>   method from a comment to its
>   signature, so the compiler can verify
>   at compile time that the type
>   constraints are not violated at run
>   time. Because the program compiles
>   without warnings, we can state with
>   certainty that it will not throw a
>   ClassCastException at run time. The
>   net effect of using generics,
>   especially in large programs, is
>   improved readability and robustness.

For example, the interface of a List is

```
public interface List<E> { 
    void add(E x);
    Iterator<E> iterator();
}
```

This means you can build a list whose contents are all of the same explicit type (not only of type Object), even if you have defined the type yourself. So, if you create a Name class you can write

```
List<Name> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then fill it with Name instances and directly retrieve Name instances from it without having to cast or otherwise worry about it because you'll always get either a Name instance or null back, never an instance of a different type.

More importantly, you cannot insert anything different from a Name instance in such a List, because it will fail at compile time.

```
nameList.add(false); //Fails!
nameList.add(new Name("John","Smith")); //Succeeds supposing Name has a 
                                        //firstName, lastName constructor
```

Comment: I read `List<T>` as "List of Types" as if T is short for Type. I have noticed `<E>` in a lot of code. Is it short for anything? Or should I just read it as "Collection of Es"

Answer (score 18):

It means that you're dealing with a collection of items with type `E`. Imagine you've got a cup of tea. Instead of tea, it could also hold coffee so it makes sense to describe the cup as a generic entity:

```
class Cup<T> { … }
```

now you could fill it, either with coffee or tea (or something else):

```
Cup<Tea> cuppa = new Cup<Tea>();
Cup<Coffee> foamee = new Cup<Coffee>();
```

In order for this to work, both `Tea` and `Coffee` would need to be types defined in your program as well.

This is a *compile-time constraint* on your code. Coming back from the (rather useless) cup example, collections (arrays, lists …) usually contain items of *one* type, e.g. integers or strings. Generics help you to express this in Java:

```
Collection<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
strList.add("Foobar"); // Works.
strList.add(42);       // Compile error!
```

Notice the compile error above? You only get this when using generics. The following code also works, but would not give the nice error message:

```
Collection strList = new ArrayList();
strList.add("Foobar"); // Works.
strList.add(42);       // Works now. Do we really want this?!
```

Comment: A touch confusing as the class Cup<T> would actually be pronounced a Cup Of T :)

Comment: @lagerdalek: that didn't escape my atttention at all. ;-)
In fact, this explanation is inspired by this: http://www.zazzle.com/c_cup_of_t_mug-168503670567870702

Comment: I got my own Cup<T> mug from zazzle after I saw Joel Pobar give an F# talk at Tech-Ed with the opening slide showing a Cup<T> mug :)